# How to know if string is null in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I want to learn if a string is null in PHP, I am using this code.

UPDATE: Working code, thanks for all your help.

```
<?php

    //Syntax blah.php?request=Value to log here

    //iPwnStore
    $request = $_GET['iPwnStore'];
    if(empty($request)) 
    {
        echo "Error, string is null!"; 
        //It always comes done to the Error, allthough $request isn't nil
    }
    else 
    {
        file_put_contents('iPwnStore.txt', $request1."\n\n", FILE_APPEND);
        echo "Success";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're setting `$request1`, but checking `$request`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because reading the code properly would reveal the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: You have a mismatched variable name...

```
$request1 = $_GET['iPwnStore'];
echo $request;
```

$request1 should be $request

```
if ($request === null)
```

Or

```
if (empty($request))
```

Comment: what about using isset also....

Comment: Yes, this would also be a good option.

Comment: OK, thanks if(empty($request) worked for me

Answer (score 1):

That way:

```
if( $request === null ) {
...
```

or by using `is_null()` function: http://php.net/is_null

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $request1 = $_GET['iPwnStore'];
  echo $request;
  if($request != '' ) 
  {
      //do something
  } else 
  {
      //do something
  }
?>
```

This should do the job.

Comment: Won't work... $resquest1 set but $request used in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

As already suggested `$request === null`, but a better solution is to check if `$_GET['iPwnStore']` is set using

```
if (isset($_GET['iPwnStore']) {
    // Add to file
} else {
    // Show some error
}
```

otherwise calling `$request = $_GET['iPwnStore']` will produce a notice.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

If you want to check if the string is null (explicitly NULL, not ''), you should use: (note the strict type comparison operator: ===, more on that here: [php comparison operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php))

```
if ($request === NULL) {
   ...
}
```

If you want to prevent putting empty content into files (ie. you want to check if string is empty) you should use this: (note that you need to do explicit typecasting to string, to prevent situation, where $request is an integer 0, in which case empty($request) will return TRUE. For more on that read here: [php empty function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
$request = (string) $request;
if (empty($request)) {
   ...
}
```